# Add new row in update method in EF Core with existing primary key with identity increment = NO

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have a problem that I have not solved it yet.

My primary key in SQL is identity increment = NO, I want to update an entity with an `ICollection` navigation property (one row is new, one row is changed. Added, and updated both done on the client-side and send to the server together).

I have to generate the primary key server-side (because identity increment is NO) when I call `DbSet.Update(entity)` I get this exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I think I get this error because I use `DbSet.Update(entity)` and want added new row that has fill ID but in SQL I set identity increment NO.
I don't want to change identity increment and I have to use `DbSet.Update(entity)` method.

How can I solve my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

EF will try to use the key value to determine the entity State. Since the ID is now set specifically, I think you have to specify the state manually for the new item otherwise EF might think it is in "Modified" state.
More from https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20984